# How to use xdebug with eclipse IDE for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

Hi my PHP project is set up on a remote test machine. I need to debug it using eclipse IDE. How shall I progress. I came to know i should prefer Xdebug rather than zend debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some tutorials you can use.

- (dead link) <s>http://www.starbowconsulting.com/blog/tao/setting-eclipse-pdt-and-xdebug</s>
- (updated link below) <s>http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930</s>
- https://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/
- http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug
- http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 4):

NOTE:  From PHP 5.3 onwards, you always need to use the "zend_extension" PHP.ini setting name, and NOT "zend_extension_ts", nor "zend_extension_debug". This took me a few hours to get working because I was following some outdated links.

This worked very well for me:  http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php